# Is there a way to hide a question for editing?

Tags: feature-request, editing, vote-to-close, deleted-questions

I was dissatisfied with one of my own questions due to a lack of clarity and focus, which became clear after other users provided comments, but I thought that it could be worked into an interesting/good question. I would like to return to it in the future after giving it more thought, to improve its focus and to increase the clarity.

I would prefer to hide the question until I am finished, so that other users won't waste their time working on an answer, since the focus might change in the future.

Which is the proper way to handle such a case? Should I delete my question or should I flag the question for closure? Or is there a feature that I am unaware of?

Comment: You can delete it. Or leave it open and leave a comment that you are currently think about how to rewrite the question in an appropriate way?

Comment: @TobiasFünke I had forgotten that the delete function basically does what I wanted to do. I thought my question would get actually deleted when I use the option so I avoided it. Thank you for the hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pressing the <kbd>Delete</kbd> button on your own question hides the question and does not delete it. It can still be viewed by going to [the user profile](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/current), *[Activity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=topactivity)* → *[Questions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=questions)* → *View all questions* → scroll to the bottom → *[Deleted Questions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/deleted-questions/current)*. It is not possible to edit the question while it’s deleted, but it can still be viewed by the author. The question can be undeleted and then edited again.

Further explanations are given
in *[Why and how are some questions deleted?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-questions)*.

Comment: I don't see a *"View all questions"*. Where is it supposed to be?

Comment: @PeterMortensen I was referring to the "Questions"  area on the user profile page, which is to the right side of the "Answers" area. Under the text field "Questions" is a View all N questions field that links to the page with all questions. Where N is the number of the users posted questions. Clicking this View all link leads to the Questions page that you have linked in the edit.  I usually click my green user icon on the upper right to get to the profile page and then click the View all questions link to get to the questions page.Is there another way to reach the Questions page directly?

Answer (score 1):

You can cut and paste your LaTeX code to [stackedit.io](https://stackedit.io/), edit it there at your leisure (it’s almost the same markdown editor as StackExchange) and then once you’re happy paste it back in place of your original.

You will need to first un-delete your post for a few moments, long enough to use the edit feature to copy the LaTeX code, and re-delete it immediately if you want your post to remain hidden except for the few moments where you captured your original LaTeX code.  Then do this again to paste the edited version back in place, obviously without deleting you newly edited post.